# Unable to call swift function from objective-c in react-native

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm fairly new to objective-c and swift so forgive me if this sounds dumb. Basically what I'm trying to do is *expose** a swift function to **both** react-native(so it can be used in JS) and to be used in objective-c. The issue I'm having is this dreaded "Duplicate interface definition for class...". I have researched and tried everything it seems but can not get rid of this error. I'm starting to wonder if is possible to do this. It seems so simple yet I just can't figure it out!

Here is my code:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
#import "MyApp-Bridging-Header.h"
```

**MyApp-Swift.h**

```
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface Counter : RCTEventEmitter
- (void)start;
- (void)stop;
@end
```

**MyApp.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(Counter)
class Counter: RCTEventEmitter {
  @objc func start(){

  }
  @objc func end(){

  }
}
```

**MyApp-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Counter, RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(start);

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(end);

@end
```

**Inside AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() function**

```
Counter* CounterInstance = [[Counter alloc] init];
[CounterInstance start];
```

If I remove the code from **MyApp-Swift.h** then I get the error "No visible @interface for..." BUT fixes the "Duplicate interface error" in **MyApp-Bridging-Header.h**. It seems like it contradicts each other!? How are you supposed to call a swift function from objective-c while also exposing the same function to JS?

Comment: Bridging header is for calling objc in swift. For calling swift in objc there is another header autogenerated by xcode. Look for SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME value in project build settings

Comment: You shouldn't import bridging header anywhere and you shouldn't declare classes there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in a project, and my setup looks like this:

**Counter.m**

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Counter, NSObject)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(start)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(stop)
@end
```

**Counter.swift**

```
import React

@objc(Counter)
class Counter: RCTEventEmitter {
    @objc func start() { /* ... */ }
    @objc func stop() { /* ... */ }
}
```

and at the call site:

```
#import "YOURAPP-Swift.h" // the compiler creates this for you. don't edit!

-(void) foo {
    Counter* cnt = [Counter new];
    [cnt start];
}
```

(no other files used or modified. In particular, the bridging header isn't needed here)

I've found https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03 very helpful when I started doing this.